# Using locale date format in Joomla modules

Tags: php, joomla, locale

How to output a date in the locale date/time format in Joomla?

I'm creating a module which is supposed to print dates. I know I can dirty-hack it like that:

```
    strftime(format_string, strotime($date));
```

... but I would like a smoother solution, that would use Joomla's built-in locale handling functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Joomla! 1.5 there is the JDate class:

```
function getLocalizedDate($date = 'now', $format_string = '%Y-%M-%D')
{
    jimport('joomla.utilities.date');
    $jdate = new JDate($date);
    return $jdate->toFormat(JText::_($format_string));
}
```

Weekday & Month names are localized by the JDate class, and additionally, if the format string is known (as '%Y-%M-%D'), it will be internationalized also - see the beginning of the file /language/xx_XX/xx_XX.ini (where xx is the used language.)

Note: JDate also applies the timezone set in configuration.php or overridden by the Joomla! user. Time fields should always be stored as +0000 GMT.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some lines of code that may be useful (excerped from a tmpl/default.php module file):

```
    <?php
    defined ( '_JEXEC' ) or die ( 'Restricted access' );

    jimport('joomla.html.html');

    if ($params->get ( "display_date", 1 )) {
        echo JHTML::_('date',$myClass->get_YYYYMMDD_Date(),JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'));
    }
```

For DATE_FORMAT_LC3=%d %B %Y and date 19991101, outputs 01 Novembre 1999. DATE_FORMAT_LC3 is a constant defined in ...\joomla15\language\fr-FR\fr-FR.ini for french translations.

And here, an excellent article: [Working with dates in Joomla!](http://www.webamoeba.co.uk/site/index.php/articles-joomla-date-time)